# How to write Assertion in Selenium Cucumber BDD?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, cucumber, assert

I want to use assertion in cucumber to verify my test output, can some please write me an example how to do the same in cucumber.

As I googled, I found that people use junit/TestNG assertions like below:

```
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Name of the Customer"));
```

Can I use the same assertions in cucumber test and how?

Comment: To add in more inputs, I am using cucumber with Junit runner class for my testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `Junit.Assert` in your Step Definition file and then you can use them as normal assert statements inside the Step Implementation.

For example,

```
@Then(​"^the total price should be (\\d+)c$"​)
​public​ ​void​ theTotalPriceShouldBeC(​int​ total) ​throws​ ​Throwable​ {
    assertEquals(total, checkout.total());
}
```

Comment: Hi , I am not able to import this class "import org.junit.Assert"

Comment: I am getting error as import can not be resolved

Comment: Please add the Junit .jar file in your project.

Comment: I have already added junit dependency in pom file as below:

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: Try removing this JUnit dependency from `pom.xml`

Comment: Yeah, I can import now. But what could be the reason for this and will i be able to do my execution without this dependency in pom file?